# Collect all of the sar data

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python, sar

**Task:**

I can `sar -u > tmp.csv` and I can `sar -r > tmp.csv` But what I need is a big table of all the sa* files of all the options.

```
sar -r -u -S -q > tmp.csv
```

does not quite do the job

**Problems**

The length of `sar -r` and lets say `sar -u` might be different. For one of them I had 3625, for the other 3650 and that is not acceptable.

**Possible solution**

for each sa* file I do `sar -r sa* > sar_r_sa*.csv`, I do that for `-r -u -S -q` and I get about 120 files of data which I could somehow merge with Python by the first column e.g. ( `7,50,01` ).

But I feel like there is a easier solution to the problem.

**Question**

How should I approach collecting all the data in a single file

Comment: Is this what you want in your output .. `CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit`  ... ?

Comment: I want data for all column `%user,..,%idle,...kbmemused,....,ldavg-1` but if you suggest a approach for `sar -u` and `sar -r`, I would figure for the rest. **IN SHORT, YES**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `join` to collect all the data in a single file:

```
join <(join <(sar -q) <(sar -S)) <(join <(sar -u) <(sar -r))
```

Comment: My issue is that in some sar files there is no records for specific options. It's mandatory that the date is synced. Do you think that `join -j 1 f1 f2` would do the job?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
paste <(sar -r) <(sar -u) <(sar -q) <(sar -S) > sar.out
```

A sample output:

```
12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit   12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle 12:00:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
12:10:01 AM   1737724   6311336     78.41     22036     85856   5583532     45.60   12:10:01 AM     all      3.92      0.00      8.85      0.01      0.00     87.22 12:10:01 AM         2       872      1.00      1.00      1.00
12:20:01 AM   1737228   6311832     78.42     22484     85860   5582312     45.59   12:20:01 AM     all      3.93      0.00      8.83      0.01      0.00     87.23 12:20:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.01      1.00
12:30:01 AM   1736764   6312296     78.42     22956     85852   5582192     45.59   12:30:01 AM     all      3.96      0.00      8.79      0.01      0.00     87.24 12:30:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
12:40:01 AM   1735636   6313424     78.44     23420     85868   5582264     45.59   12:40:01 AM     all      3.92      0.00      8.85      0.01      0.00     87.22 12:40:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
12:50:01 AM   1734644   6314416     78.45     23884     85872   5582248     45.59   12:50:01 AM     all      3.90      0.00      8.86      0.01      0.00     87.22 12:50:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
01:00:01 AM   1733992   6315068     78.46     24356     85876   5582252     45.59   01:00:01 AM     all      3.95      0.00      8.79      0.01      0.00     87.24 01:00:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
01:10:01 AM   1731508   6317552     78.49     24836     85892   5583444     45.60   01:10:01 AM     all      3.95      0.00      8.80      0.01      0.00     87.24 01:10:01 AM         2       872      1.00      1.00      1.00
01:20:01 AM   1732028   6317032     78.48     25304     85880   5582144     45.59   01:20:01 AM     all      3.95      0.00      8.80      0.01      0.00     87.24 01:20:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
01:30:01 AM   1730776   6318284     78.50     25752     85888   5582324     45.59   01:30:01 AM     all      3.95      0.00      8.79      0.01      0.00     87.25 01:30:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
01:40:01 AM   1729152   6319908     78.52     26224     85892   5582404     45.60   01:40:01 AM     all      3.95      0.00      8.79      0.01      0.00     87.25 01:40:01 AM         2       871      1.00      1.00      1.00
```

Note: You would be having duplicate time columns in the final output